# Joined selection from two tables

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using `Django` with a `mysql` database.

I have the table `Question` that contains the fields: `id, text, section_id` and I have the table `CompletedQuestion` that has the fields: `id, question_id` where the field `question_id` is foreign key to `Question.id`.

My `models.py` contains:

```
class Question(mixins.OrdMixin, mixins.EqMixin, models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey('Section',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='owner')
    text = models.TextField()

class CompletedQuestion(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey('Question',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='question_source')
```

I want to check whether there are completed questions in `CompletedQuestion` where belong to a specific `section_id` from `Question`.

My current query is the following but it's not the proper one:

```
quest_id = Question.objects.filter(section_id = section_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `__isnull=True|False` filter you can use to check if any related model exists, I dont really understand what you mean but something like:

```
Question.objects.filter(section_id=section_id, question_source__isnull=False)
```

Or come from the other direction like:

```
CompletedQuestion.objects.filter(question__section_id=section_id) \
    .values_list("question_id",flat=True).distinct()
```

To get a list of question-IDs that have any related CompletedQuestions

Comment: I prefer the second option! Thank you very much!